# Test if data was set correctly with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've got service:

```js
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LanguageService {
    protected activeLanguage = '';

    constructor(protected translateService: TranslateService) {
    }

    async load(userLanguage: string) {
        userLanguage = String(userLanguage).toLowerCase();
        this.activeLanguage = userLanguage;
        await this.translateService.use(this.activeLanguage).toPromise();
    }
    
    getActiveLanguage(): string[] {
        return this.activeLanguage;
    }
}
```

I want to test if active language was set correctly. This is how I tried to do that:

```js
import { TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LanguageService } from './language.service';

fdescribe('LanguageService', () => {
    let injector: TestBed;
    let testee: LanguageService;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           //...
        });
        injector = getTestBed();
        testee = injector.get(LanguageService);
    });

    it('should create', async () => {
        expect(testee).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should load configuration', async () => {
        const lang = 'en';
        const languageServiceSpy = spyOn(testee, 'load').and.callThrough();

        // make sure they haven't been called yet
        expect(languageServiceSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

        testee.load(lang);
        expect(languageServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    it('should return active language', async () => {
        const activeLanguage = testee.getActiveLanguage();
        expect(activeLanguage).toEqual('en');
});
```

However, my test fails with error `Error: Expected '' to equal 'en'.` 
How do I preserve the result of first test?

I know that there's `ComponentFixture` where you can trigger `detectChanges`, but this is service, not a component, so it doesn't seem correct to use it. Anyway, I am still new to frontent testing so I'd love to hear what you'd do.

Or should I just get the active language in the same test? Since there are other methods as well I wanted to have each test  for the rather than one huge test

Answer (score 1):

Currently your `LanguageService` is created each time again in `beforeEach`, hence you should test for active language in the test that previously calls `LanguageService#load`. Probably you also need an `await` in front of `LanguageService#load`.

```
await testee.load(lang);
```